# Что учить дальше?

Tags: java, oracle, книги

Недавно закончил читать Head First Java O'Reilly, прошел бесплатные уровни на javarush, в копилке 2 небольших проектика (250 и 500 строк). Подскажите, как дальше развиваться? Цель - устроиться на работу Java Junior-ом в г. Оренбурге. Основы благодаря книге и сайту знаю вроде, а чем теперь заниматься - нет, так как не думаю, что за одну книгу и пару программок дорос до джуниора и могу устроиться хотя бы на стажировку. Подскажите, что дальше делать, чтобы в будущем не остаться без работы? Также есть еще один вопрос: есть ли смысл учить SQL, и если да, то насколько долго он учится?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Посвятите время изучению ООП - не знаю, сколько этой теме уделено внимания в вышеозначенной книге, однако для языков вроде Java это основополагающая тема, знать которую следует назубок.
2. Обязательно займитесь изучением алгоритмов и структур данных. С одной стороны, конечно, в промышленной разработке редко приходится писать свои велосипеды для сортировок/поисков/etc, с другой же стороны, это фундаментальные знания, которые всегда будут полезны и помогут лучше понимать код и писать его более грамотно.
3. Касательно SQL - тема эта немаловажная - мало какая серьезная программа обходится без работы с БД, поэтому учите обязательно. Даже если всю жизнь будете использовать только ORM (пока не заморачивайтесь над тем, что это), все равно собственно SQL знать следует. Помимо SQL, обратите внимание на нормализацию БД, хотя бы обзорно, знание полезное. В части того, что нужно знать джуниору, учится недолго.
4. Наверняка стоит уделить внимание ряду стандартных вопросов типа многопоточности, работе с файлами, XML, работе с сетью, обобщениям, типам данных. Конечно, знать все это от джуниора досконально вряд ли кто потребует, однако же эти знания ценны сами по себе с утилитарной точки зрения - рано или поздно вы столкнетесь с этими аспектами.
5. Пишите код, много кода хорошего и разного. Читайте код, как чужой так и свой, это всегда полезно.
6. Обзорно можно онакомиться с такими страшными словами, как паттерны проектирования и рефакторинг (на самом деле этот пункт совсем не обязателен для джуниора, но впоследствии  станет таковым).

Comment: А можно по пунктам 1-3 хорошие книги на русском языке??

Comment: По первому пункту -  думаю, учить ООП стоит без отрыва от Java. Сам я Java не занимаюсь, поэтому абсолютно точных рецептов не дам, но вроде бы "Философию Java" от Эккеля в целом хвалят. Знающие Java люди могут меня дополнить, поправить  или опровенргнуть.

По второму - из классики -  Кормен либо Вирт. Можете попробовать Кнута, но это хардкор, вам вряд ли понадобится.

По третьему пункту. Я учил SQL в основном на практике, хотя слышал, что очень хвалят Мартина Грабера.

Comment: @expo1on, сейчас читаю книгу про ООП. Автор Бертран Мейер и называется "Почувствуй класс". Скажу, книга очень мощная и достойная того, чтобы ее прочитали. Рекомендуется даже опытным. Из минусов:

1. Читается тяжело, заставляет очень хорошо думать над каждой мыслью автора. 

2. Куски кода в ней на Eiffel вместо Java или С-подобного. 

Но читать можно и нужно! ;) Настоятельно рекомендую эту книгу Вам прочесть.

Comment: @DreamChild, что скажете по поводу той книги http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/19665827/ ? Я правильно понял, что она тоже по алгоритмам?

Comment: >Я правильно понял, что она тоже по алгоритмам?

Нет, неправильно. Это совсем другая область знаний (впрочем, не менее полезная). Про книгу не скажу ничего - вижу ее впервые, но в ближайшее время без практики, реальной работы эта тема вряд ли будет для вас обязательной, лучше сосредоточиться на других вопросах.

Answer (score 0):

Советую джавараш купить, месячную подписку и пройти максимум за этот период, там много полезного, я пожалел 100 баксов по акции, безлимит. Купил 2 раза месячную :)
До 30-го уровня много интересных и сложных задач, и теория там отлично разжевана.

Также добавлю, что стоит почитать:

1. Thinking in Java, лучше на англ. 4 издание сразу читать.
2. JUnit для тестирования.
3. GIT, сейчас про это все спрашивают, туда же можно слить проекты свои.
4. Maven, сборка проектов.
5. SQL, можно проходить задачки на sql-ex.ru, практически реальный опыт.
6. Коллекции, многопоточность, немного concurrency.
7. После изучения Java core, почитать Spring in Action, самый популярный фреймворк, заодно и запилить какой-то проект на нем.